# Getting error while trying to install cldr

Tags: javascript, angular, cldr

```
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-units-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
Whops Error making request.
```

The above error is coming while trying do :

```
npm i cldr-data
```

We have an angular project that is being used since long, and it has cldr-data in its package. Not sure why this issue is coming up now if someone tries to reinstall the project or just the cldr.

Any help would be appreciated.

Full Error:

```
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-core/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-dates- 
modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-buddhist- 
modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
```

GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-chinese-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-coptic-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-dangi-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-ethiopic-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-hebrew-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-indian-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-islamic-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-japanese-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-persian-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-roc-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-localenames-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-misc-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-segments-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
GET `https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-units-modern/archive/36.0.0.zip`
Whops Error making request.
Error: error request aborted
at createError (C:\newui-v2\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
at IncomingMessage.handlerStreamAborted (C:\newui-v2\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:301:18)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:426:11)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
at net.js:673:12
at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:563:7)

Please report this full log at https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-downloader

Answer (score 0):

remove the package from package.json and then install it again.
if this didn't work then change the network connection and check it once.

If this nor work then reverts back.

Comment: I have tried running only npm i cldr-data....that gives the error too..

Comment: try to change your network connection.